# Json stringify in JS and decoding in php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

**js**

```
var sim_list=[];
var simvalue = $('input[name="simnamecbx"]:checked').each(function(){
    var sim_name=this.value.split(" ")[0];
    console.log("simname:",sim_name);
    sim_list.push({
        sim_name
    });
);
console.log(sim_list);
var simulation_list = JSON.stringify(sim_list);     
$.ajax({ url: 'addprogram.php',
     data: {addpgmname:addprogname, addpgmcomp:addprogcomp, addpgmdate:addprogdate, simselvalue:simulation_list},
     type: 'post',
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(output){
         var a = output;
         console.log(a);
     }
});
```

**php**

```
$simvalue = json_decode($_POST["simselvalue"],true);
foreach($simvalue as $key => $value) {
    print_r($value);
}
```

**Question**

When I execute the above php I get the values as

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sim_name] => 12
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sim_name] => 13
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [sim_name] => 14
        )

)
```

But I want the result to be like 12, 13, 14 which can be inserted into mysql table. Please explain how to parse this array that I get from javascript.

Comment: $simvalue is an array so simply use foreach loop and insert it

Comment: Is there any error on console???

Comment: above output you must be getting on `print_r($_POST["simselvalue"])` right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you are pushing an object with `sim_name` on to your array instead of the actual value. This actually only works in ES6 compatible browsers which makes your error invisible.

The problem is this part in your javascript code:

```
sim_list.push({
    sim_name
});
```

In ECMAScript 6 this is the equivalent of the following:

```
sim_list.push({
    sim_name: sim_name
});
```

Thus you are pushing an object with the `sim_name` property set to the number (e.g. 12, 13, 14).

What I think that you want to do is the following:

```
sim_list.push(sim_name)
```

This will push only the number onto the array.

All together now:

**JS**

```
var sim_list = []

$('input[name="simnamecbx"]:checked').each(function () {
  var sim_name = this.value.split(' ')[0]
  sim_list.push(sim_name)
})

var data = {
  addpgmname: addprogname,
  addpgmcomp: addprogcomp,
  addpgmdate: addprogdate,
  simselvalue: JSON.stringify(sim_list)
}

$.ajax({
  url: 'addprogram.php',
  data: data,
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (output) {
    console.log(output)
  }
})
```

**PHP**

```
$simvalue = json_decode($_POST["simselvalue"]);

print("The selected values was: " . implode($simvalue, ", "));
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST["simselvalue"], true) // true = associative array

foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    // database query
}
```